# Is there any open source implementation of Litecoin wallet integration in Java?

Tags: wallet, litecoin

I want to integrate Litecoin wallet.Is there any way to do it

Comment: @Max Vernon, 
May I know how the question is too broad this is the second time my question has been put on hold,If you can't answer any question say it directly why need to hold the question .How the question above can be broad ,If you want to hold please provide a valid reason